# How to loop over and array with underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'm trying to loop over an Array using Underscore, I have this:

```js
var friends = [
  {
    name: 'Jimmy',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'Anna',
    age: 19
  },
  {
    name: 'Alina',
    age: '22'
  },
  {
    name: 'Carl',
    age: '22'
  }
];

var names = _(friends).pluck('name');

for(i = 0; i < friends.length; i++){
  $('ul').append('<li>' + names[i] + '</li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

I'm trying to do the same using underscore's each method, but I can't achieve it, I'm trying doing something like this:

```
_(friends).each(function(namessss, i){
  $('ul').append('<li>' + names[i] + '</li>');
});
```

This actually works, but what I don't understand is why?! What's the first parameter for, it doesn't matter what I write there, it works and I wonder how to do this, and why this way works, thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? http://underscorejs.org/#each. *If list is a JavaScript object, iteratee's arguments will be (value, key, list).* `console.log(namessss)` It does not matter what you name it since you do not use it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#each):

> Each invocation of iteratee is called with three arguments: (element, index, list). If list is a JavaScript object, iteratee's arguments will be (value, key, list)

Your code works no matter what you write for that first argument, because you never actually use that argument (the value itself). Instead you just reference an index on the `names` array which you have defined outside of this loop.

If you'd like to actually use the value in the `each` loop, you can use something like this:

```
_(friends).each(function(friend, i){
  $('ul').append('<li>' + friend.name + '</li>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this would be a reasonably typical way :-

```js
var friends = [
  {
    name: 'Jimmy',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'Anna',
    age: 19
  },
  {
    name: 'Alina',
    age: '22'
  },
  {
    name: 'Carl',
    age: '22'
  }
];

var names = _(friends).pluck('name');

_.each(names, function(name){
  $('ul').append('<li>' + name + '</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Why didn't I try this before? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The each method has the syntax...

```
_.each(list, callbackFunc);
```

where callbackFunc has the syntax...

```
function callbackFunc(element, index, list) {}
```

Your code just happens to work because you stored the name values in the names array which you are then accessing using the index passed to your callback function. A better way to write the code would be...

```
_(friends).each(function(friend){
  $('ul').append('<li>' + friend.name + '</li>');
});
```